# Creating and opening a file in it's default app on Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am making a Xamarin.Forms app and having trouble getting a file to open in it's default application on Android.  I have file data as bytes in a local database and I would like to be able to view this in the default app for it's type.  I assume that I will first need to write the file to the file system and then open it.  As far as I can tell opening the file is straightforward:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
intent.SetDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.StartActivity(intent);
```

I can get the mime type from the extension easily.  However creating the file and getting it's uri is proving difficult.  All attempts that I have made so far are either throwing exceptions or the target app is saying it cannot access the resource.  The following code doesn't throw an exception but does fail because the target app cannot access the file:

```
// create directory
var activity = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
var previewFolder = new File(activity.GetExternalFilesDir(Environment.DirectoryDownloads), "previews");
previewFolder.Mkdirs();

// create file
var file = File.CreateTempFile(fileName, null, _previewFolder);
file.SetReadable(true);

var stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
await stream.WriteAsync(content, 0, content.Length);
stream.Close();

// get uri
var uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(activity, "my.app.id.fileprovider", file);
```

The fileprovider section in AndroidManifest.xml looks like:

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

and the file_paths.xml looks like (I really don't understand how this is meant to be configured):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <root-path name="root" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
    <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

EDIT:
The main problem seems to have been that:

```
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
```

needed to be:

```
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider):

> A FileProvider can only generate a content URI for files in
>   directories that you specify beforehand. To specify a directory,
>   specify the its storage area and path in XML, using child elements of
>   the  element. For example, the following paths element tells
>   FileProvider that you intend to request content URIs for the images/
>   subdirectory of your private file area.

In your case you have:

```
<files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
```

So you need to create a path: `Pictures` the third party application will see it by its alias name: `my_images`. Don't use the temp files as you did

```
var file = File.CreateTempFile(fileName, null, _previewFolder);
```

Instead, use the internal dir:

```
File root = Context.getFilesDir();
File imagesRoot = new File(root, "Pictures");
File imageFile = new File(imagesRoot, "myFile.png");
```

Also grand permissions by executing the below steps:

> To grant an access permission to a content URI returned from
>   getUriForFile(), do one of the following: Call the method
>   Context.grantUriPermission(package, Uri, mode_flags) for the
>   content:// Uri, using the desired mode flags. This grants temporary
>   access permission for the content URI to the specified package,
>   according to the value of the the mode_flags parameter, which you can
>   set to FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION, FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
>   or both. The permission remains in effect until you revoke it by
>   calling revokeUriPermission() or until the device reboots. Put the
>   content URI in an Intent by calling setData(). Next, call the method
>   Intent.setFlags() with either FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
>   FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION or both. Finally, send the Intent to
>   another app. Most often, you do this by calling setResult().
>   Permissions granted in an Intent remain in effect while the stack of
>   the receiving Activity is active. When the stack finishes, the
>   permissions are automatically removed. Permissions granted to one
>   Activity in a client app are automatically extended to other
>   components of that app.

Comment: This didn't get me any closer.  I get the following exception at the `FileProvider.GetUriForFile(activity, "my.app.id.fileprovider", file);` line: Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/my.app.id/files/Previews/myfile.txt (I had put a lines in my file_paths.xml for previews: `<external-files-path name="my_previews" path="Previews" />`).

Comment: Also is there a reason that `File.CreateTempFile` would behave differently than `new File`?  As long as they have the same root folder I would have thought the only difference is that CreateTempFile gives you a unique file name which is preferable in my case.

Comment: So I worked out it needs to be `<files-path>` rather than `<external-files-path>` if using `Context.getFilesDir();` but while that gets rid of the exception, the app trying to display the file still cannot access it.

Comment: @rcarrington edited. Ok, so now it's a different problem. Can you start it in a new question or attach the code of the other app in here.

Comment: It's exactly the same problem.  In this case the app trying to display the file is Chrome as that appears to be the default handler for text files.  It just displays a message saying it does not have access to the resource.  If I instead choose to open it in the Android HTML viewer it get a similar error message that gives the path that it cannot access as content://my.app.id.fileprovider/my_previews/myfile.txt.

Comment: @rcarrington it's not a good test, browsers can have some security limitation for opening local files. Try to open it with some text viewer app, for browser you might be able to open a local server and show it view local:// access

Comment: I can navigate to the file in the File app and open it in Chrome fine so there is nothing wrong with the file itself and there are no security warnings.

Comment: @rcarrington I see. Ok, so then we are missing here some thing else

Comment: @rcarrington What about permissions? Check my last edit

Comment: The key seems to have been setting `ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission` in the `intent.SetFlags` call.  The FileProvider section in the manifest is set to grantUriPermissions and none of the examples I looked at did this so I'm still a little confused how this works.  However thanks for the time and effort you put into this.